# Drop down(Spinner) is not showing in design window of android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am a beginner in android. I have a question why the spinner is not showing in design window?. For your help I have added a code below

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Text View!"
    android:paddingRight="100dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:id="@+id/brand"


    />


<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/color"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/color"
    android:id="@+id/find_beer"

    />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/color"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
    >
</Spinner>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALo50.jpg)

Comment: Post your entire layout XML file.

Comment: @Ankesh content_find_beer.xml is         Spinner
        android:id="@+id/color"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
        
        >
    </Spinner>  String.xml is                                           
     <resources>
    <string name="app_name">BeerAdvisor</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string></resources>               & content_find_beer.xml i hv already aded in qstn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Constraints` you are using are incorrect. Change your layout as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/color"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"></Spinner>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/find_beer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"    
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/color"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/color"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/color" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/brand"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="57dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="57dp"
        android:paddingRight="100dp"
        android:text="Text View!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />  

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Setting following attribute:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

**Means following:**

The view should be only big enough to enclose its content

Even if you correct your constraints, remember to add some content to the Spinner otherwise you will just see drop down arrow on the screen.

Comment: No the code doesn't work. The entire code was            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".FindBeerActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_find_beer">

    <TextView  Rest same as above described by me

Comment: Delete you entire code and replace it with what I have pasted and check if that works

Comment: Great! Remember to mark it as accepted by clicking the tick, so that others can benefit too. Enjoy coding

Answer (score 1):

change the layout type like a linearlayout with orientation vertical or relativelayout set layout after you set value with using java code or xml using resources

```
<resources>
<string-array name="planets_array">
    <item>Mercury</item>
    <item>Venus</item>
    <item>Earth</item>
    <item>Mars</item>
    <item>Jupiter</item>
    <item>Saturn</item>
    <item>Uranus</item>
    <item>Neptune</item>
</string-array>
```

java code

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
// Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
        R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
// Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
// Apply the adapter to the spinner
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

using layout xml into spinner tag

```
android:entries="@array/planets_array"
```

Comment: Please tell me I only wanted to see the drop down and do not wanted to perform any task. Is it impossible without adding a code in java file

Answer (score 0):

XML code.

```
<Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/spCountry"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
```

Code for activity

```
Spinner spCountry;

spRole = (Spinner)getView().findViewById(R.id.spCountry);

String[] arRoleSpinner = {"India","USA","NWZ","SA", "WI","ENG"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arRoleSpinner);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item);
        spRole.setAdapter(adapter);

        spRole.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                ((TextView) adapterView.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                ((TextView) adapterView.getChildAt(0)).setTextSize(12);


            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Please tell me without adding code in Activity, is it impossible to display drop down list on design window

Comment: I agree that the functionality does not  work. for exp the button would not perform any task but it is shows its appearance on design window. Similarly if i have only spinner and do nothing it must be shown on design window.

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
<Spinner
android:id="@+id/color"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginTop="72dp" ></Spinner>
```

because in spinner (drop down list) we add items at run time (in java code) so it show when we run app. and also every change in java code like color change , Visibility etc show when we run the app.

and also visit this https://www.javatpoint.com/android-spinner-example

Comment: Java Point is a good solution. But tell me one thing the button and text is showing on design window, Drop down list is not coming.

Comment: because in spinner (drop down list) we add items at run time (in java code) so it show when we run app. and also every change in java code like color change , Visibility etc show when we run the app.

Comment: thnaxx So it is the reason behind the process. Thank you so much again